# R: Identical() and Missing Values?

Tags: r, validation

I have a dataframe (let's call it `foo`) with many columns and two rows. If I type `foo[1, ] == foo[2, ]`, I only see values of NA or TRUE. However, if I type `identical(foo[1, ], foo[2, ])` I receive `FALSE`. Does identical() not handle missing values?

Note: I thought perhaps it was an issue where the column values did not match for the two rows, but I check in Excel and the values appear to be identical. Perhaps this is a data issue. I can't produce a working example, so here is the actual file: https://ufile.io/6kj5z

Comment: The documentation for [`identical`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/identical.html) should have given a pretty clear explanation. It only returns a single TRUE or FALSE logical value.

Comment: I, like many, won't download from an unknown / untrusted data source.  Are you sure you can't produce a reproducible example, even if it's just a few rows and columns?